# How Do I Print things on the same line from two print statements which are in two for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a problem in my code first see the code I have a list

```
numbers = [3, 10, 12 ,14, 15, 17, 20]
```

I want to print all the numbers in the list but I want to have the number of the element before the element so my output should be

```
1 3
2 10
3 12
```

and so on I have tried this

```
for m in range(1 , len(numbers) + 1)
    print(m , end = '')
for i in numbers:
    print(numbers)
```

How can I acomplish this

Comment: Do you have to have two for loops or can you [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them together?

Comment: `for i,j in enumerate(numbers):print(i,j)`

Comment: You've set things up in such a way that that's going to be hard. Why not just `for i, num in enumerate(numbers): print(i, num);`? Making this two loops and expecting the output you want will require some messing around with the console.

Comment: @wwii But the best way would be to use `enumerate`.

Comment: @Ch3steR - I wasn't sure if it was a toy example.

Comment: `i` isn't a great variable name, in `for i in numbers:`, since names like `i` are usually reserved for indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print statement accepts multiple arguments and prints them with a space in between.

```
print("hi", "there")
-> "hi there"
```

So you want:

```
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    print(i, numbers[i])
```

Note, Python indexes from 0, not 1.

Comment: Surely index in python starts from 0, not from 1 but I want to print from 1

Comment: If that's the case, then in the print statement do print(i+1, numbers[i]). I just speak from experience that is much easier always to start loops from 0!

Comment: Thanks for your help Alan I just did that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate`, which will give you the index first. (and add 1 if you want the location).

```
numbers = [3, 10, 12 ,14, 15, 17, 20]
for idx,m in enumerate(numbers):
    print(idx+1,' ',m)
```

Output:

```
1   3
2   10
3   12
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are beginner so here is simple solution

```
numbers = [3, 10, 12 ,14, 15, 17, 20]
count =0
for i in   numbers:
    count+=1
    print(str(count)+ "  " + str(i))
```